# D3.js events firing on load

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a chart with D3 that will update when a submit button is clicked, however instead of firing when the button is clicked, the event happens as the page is loaded.

For example:

```
d3.select("#updatedata").on("click", alert('test'));
```

The alert happens immediately and does not happen when the button is clicked.

Am I missing something obvious?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the handler in a function:

```
d3.select("#updatedata").on("click", function() { alert('test'); });
```